# Force Remove a Google Glass Contact

Tags: google-mirror-api

Is there a way to force delete a contact on Glass?

I've been playing with the QuickStart project on Google App Engine and accidentally deleted the client id that was used to create the contact.

So now I can't login with the proper client id to delete that contact via REST api.

I tried restarting with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing permissions for the Glassware, either through the [connected sites](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens) page, or via the [MyGlass](https://glass.google.com/myglass) page.

Comment: This app doesn't show up on MyGlass because it is just a slightly modified version of the quick start app.

And it doesn't show up on connected sites anymore either, presumably because Google doesn't know what the project is.